# How to enable python provider for Neovim installed via flatpak?

Tags: apt, python, flatpak, neovim

I'm new to `flatpak` so I don't really know how exactly it works.

I tried to install python3 on my native system using `apt` and install `pynvim` with `pip3 install --user --upgrade pynvim`. (I did this when I was using `snap` and it's perfectly fine)

But still, my neovim cannot seem to have the provider working. This following is my health check result.

```
## Python 3 provider (optional)
  - INFO: Disabled (g:loaded_python3_provider=1).  This might be due to some previous error.
  - WARNING: No Python executable found that can `import neovim`. Using the first available executable for diagnostics.
  - ERROR: Python provider error:
    - ADVICE:
      - provider/pythonx: Could not load Python 3:
          /usr/bin/python3 does not have the "neovim" module. :help |provider-python|
          /usr/bin/python3.7 does not have the "neovim" module. :help |provider-python|
          python3.6 not found in search path or not executable.
          python3.5 not found in search path or not executable.
          python3.4 not found in search path or not executable.
          python3.3 not found in search path or not executable.
          /usr/bin/python is Python 2.7 and cannot provide Python 3.
  - INFO: Executable: Not found
```

EDIT1:

I made some progress on this.
I found that the `neovim` flatpak app has `host` enabled so that I can access my native python3 executable through `/var/run/host/usr/bin/python3`. However, the path to everything that python3 depends on will need to be prepended with `/var/run/host/`, which is still not happening. Here is the new health check message.

```
## Python 3 provider (optional)
  - INFO: Disabled (g:loaded_python3_provider=1).  This might be due to some previous error.
  - INFO: Using: g:python3_host_prog = "/var/run/host/usr/bin/python3"
  - INFO: Executable: /var/run/host/usr/bin/python3
  - ERROR: Command error (job=5, exit code 1): `'/var/run/host/usr/bin/python3' -c 'import sys; print(".".join(str(x) for x in sys.version_info[:3]))'` (in '/home/haowenl/.var/app/io.neovim.nvim/config/nvim')
    Output: /var/run/host/usr/bin/python3: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /var/run/host/usr/bin/python3)
    Stderr: /var/run/host/usr/bin/python3: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /var/run/host/usr/bin/python3)
  - ERROR: Command error (job=6, exit code 1): `'/var/run/host/usr/bin/python3' -c 'import sys; sys.path.remove(""); import neovim; print(neovim.__file__)'` (in '/home/haowenl/.var/app/io.neovim.nvim/config/nvim')
    Output: /var/run/host/usr/bin/python3: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /var/run/host/usr/bin/python3)
    Stderr: /var/run/host/usr/bin/python3: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /var/run/host/usr/bin/python3)
  - WARNING: Unexpected Python version. This could lead to confusing error messages.
  - WARNING: Python 3.3+ is recommended.
  - INFO: Python version: /var/run/host/usr/bin/python3: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /var/run/host/usr/bin/python3)
  - INFO: pynvim version: unable to load neovim Python module
  - ERROR: pynvim is not installed.
    Error: unable to load neovim Python module
    - ADVICE:
      - Run in shell: pip3 install pynvim
```

Thank you!